# Missing library warning on Cordova/iOS 3.0.0

Tags: ios, cordova

When I use create or build on CLI with PhoneGap 3.0 I get:

[warning] missing library cordova/ios/3.0.0

After that it downloads the missing library and continues, but does anyone know how to get rid of the warning?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this only shows up the first time you do this and the bug is already fixed:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/150

Comment: That's true and it is actually me on that conversation on GitHub. But I forgot to update stackoverflow with the solution.